# How to hide Facebook's Send Dialog?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I cannot figure out how to hide Send Dialog.
I read the [Facebook Send Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/) article.

What I am trying to achieve is to hide the popup window by pushing the button to send the dialog. Can someone explain me how to use "POST" to hide the window and at the same time send the content of FB dialog to other people?

```
  FB.init({appId: '123050457758183', xfbml: true, cookie: true});

  FB.ui({
      method: 'send',
      name: 'People Argue Just to Win',
      link: 'http://www.nytimes.com/2011/06/15/arts/people-argue-just-to-win-scholars-assert.html',
      });
```

Comment: The dialog hides itself when the user clicks Send or closes it

Comment: Click send! 
That is to say,when I click button, the massage have be send!

Comment: So you want to submit the Send dialog automatically, without user interaction? That would be spamming however you try to look at it.

Comment: I want to a certain user not to leave any message to other user.
Just send the specific message like link,name,description...
But that isn't spamming.